# Need a Hyperlink control to do several things at once

Tags: vb.net, facebook, hyperlink, datalist

On my site I have a DataList full of image thumbnails. The thumbnails are HyperLink controls that, when clicked, offer an enlarged view of the source image (stored in my database).

My client wants a facebook Like button on each image and I was hoping to put that in the lightbox window that appears when you click on a thumbnail.
My challenge here is that to generate the info for the Like, I need to create meta tags and each image should, preferably, create it's own meta tags on the fly.

What I can't figure out is how to make the HyperLink click open the lightbox AND create the meta tags at the same time.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

For a live view of the site, go to http://www.dossier.co.za

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that we approach similar problems is to hook the onclick event of the href in javascript.

Depending on exactly what you need to do, you can even prevent the standard browser behavior for the hyperlink from executing by returning false from the javascript method.

And in some cases, we just use the hyperlink for "show" by setting the href to "#".

Here is an example that combines all of these concepts:

```
<a href="#" id="lnkFile" runat="server" onclick="javascript:{cmdFile_Click(); return false}" title="View the file">File Name</a>
```

In this case, the specified javascript is executed, there is no real hyperlink, and the browser doesn't try to navigate to the specified URL because we return false in the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Classname to the opening table tag like class="tbl_images" so we can use JQuery to access it.  Capture the click on the td and pickup the id of the item.  Pass that id to your code as required to generate your meta tags.  In the following when the user clicks on an anchor in a td, a function will run.

I use this all the time to access attributes in the td so i can run a function.  You could use something like this to pickup values from your image/anchor and create something...

```
      $("#tbl_images > tbody > tr ").each(function () {
          //get the id of the tr (if required)
          var id = $(this).attr("id");
          var ImageTitle = $(this).find("img.Image_Class_Name").attr("title");

          //on click of anchor with classname of lighthouse run function, 
          //passing in our id or other data in the row to our function
          $(this).find("td: > a.lighthouse").click(function () {
              //update script for this record
              MyFunction(id,ImageTitle);
          });
      });
```